# How to save customized kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a logstash-elasticsearch-kibana local setup and I have a problem when it comes to save Kibana dashboards. Selecting the "Save" option I get the following error: "Save failed Dashboard could not be saved to Elasicsearch" I'm using the logstash dashboard that comes with Kibana and after some modifications I tried to save it getting this error.

Initially, I thought my user and password are incorrect and I might have forgot the same. Then I changed my user and password via the following command:-

In the documentation its given

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.myhost.org.htpasswd user
```

So, I did the following:-

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/conf.d/testing.somedomain.com.htpasswd user
```

I also tried

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/conf.d/kibana.testing.somedomain.com.htpasswd user
```

but still no luck.

Any leads would be of great help. I read some post on SO but was not of much help.

Comment: Do you have a .kibana index?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: check it in elasticsearch http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/

Comment: No. There isnt any. All I see are the indices like `logstash-2015.03.19` etc.

Comment: How should I create one?